# Firestore query with equal and higher than compound is not working in PHP

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm calling the firebase store via PHP, when I call:

```
        $query = $collection
            ->where('c', '=', $vars['cid']);
```

or

```
        $query = $collection
            ->where('t', '>', $params['lastSync']);
```

It works fine.. however when I combine it stops working:

```
        $query = $collection
            ->where('c', '=', $vars['cid'])
            ->where('t', '>', $params['lastSync']);
```

How can I solve this?

Thank you so much!
Maarten

Answer (score 0):

Since "stops working" is not specific detail, assumption is it gives an error message, whether seen or unseen.

According to [firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) on compound queries [emphasis added]:

> Compound queries
>
> You can also chain multiple where() methods to create more specific
>   queries (logical AND). However, to combine the equality operator (==)
>   with a range or array-contains clause (<, <=, >, >=, or
>   array_contains), **make sure to create a composite index**.

From [firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) on indexing:

> If you attempt a compound query with a range clause that doesn't map
>   to an existing index, you receive an error. The error message includes
>   a direct link to create the missing index in the Firebase console.

Comment: I unfortunately don't get an error message back so it's hard to tell at the moment.

I've read that part, however I copied their example and it doesn't work as they give it. This is also the example posted above. 

How do I catch this error? As it's not output right now by the official library for php.

Comment: The other, even simpler, explanation is that there are no documents that meet both criteria. (Changing assumption to: "working" means results are returned).

Comment: There definitely should be results.

Comment: Ok to recap: composite index exists; no errors thrown (firebase, php, webserver, browser console); expect results. Who are the "they" in _as they give it_? Do "they" have a support area that could give more help? Is it because `t` is a datetime? FYI [show all php errors and warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/showing-all-errors-and-warnings/5438125#5438125)

Comment: You were right in the end about the indexing. I run the script standalone and then did get the message. Thank you!